# How can I get the 'No Match Output' from a Lookup Transformation in SSIS 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ssis, lookup

How can I get the 'No Match Output' from a Lookup Transformation in SSIS 2005?

My past experience is in SSIS 2008, and I know that in 2008 this is an option on every Lookup transformation, but I have found that in SSIS 2005 this is not an option. Is there a reasonable work around to this, without having to use 'Ignore Failure' in Error handling.

The package I am working with needs to incrementally update data within a table. Currently it wipes the table clean and repopulates the data each run. This doesn't work well with the application side of the coin, and the package needs to be altered to only update records that have changed or add new records into the table. My plan was to compare the ODS table to the DM  table using the lookup action, and I need the non-match output from the lookup to determine the changes.

Thanks

KJ

Comment: Beyond William Todd Salzman's response, the only other routes I know of are to roll your own lookup task via .NET (I had to lookup against an ODBC source) or use merge transformation. If you need me to sketch either of those out, let me know.

Comment: @billinkc , i have the same problem as the original poster, i would wish to know how you  rolled your own lookup task via .NET

Comment: @jksn17, did get a solution to this problem, if yes what was the solution?. I am having a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate workaround is to use the Ignore Failure option for SSIS 2005.  That was updated in 2008 to add the No Match Output option.

Answer (score 0):

No match is not available in SSIS 2005 You need to use ignore failure option. Lookup transformation is drastically changed in 2008 and 2008R2.